# Automapper - Map custom object nested inside List of object

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper, nested-map

I need to map `List<Source>` to `List<Dest>`, The issue is that Source contains `NestedObject` inside it & Dest also contains a `NestedObject` inside it. I need to map these two also while my List is being mapped. I have tried everything but either the nested object always remains `null` and doesnt get mapped or I get the following exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types:
>   .....

**Structure of Source & Destinations:**

**Source:**

```
 public class Source {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public CustomObjectSource NestedProp{ get; set; }
        }
  public class CustomObjectSource {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value{ get; set; }
        }
```

**Destination:**

```
 public class Destination {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public CustomObjectDest NestedProp{ get; set; }
        }
  public class CustomObjectDest {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value{ get; set; }
        }
```

**What I have tried:**
I have the following code, tried several other approaches also but to no avail:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
                {
                    c.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                      .AfterMap((Src, Dest) => Dest.NestedProp = new Dest.NestedProp
                      {
                          Key = Src.NestedProp.Key,
                          Value = Src.NestedProp.Value
                      });
                });                
                var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var destinations = mapper.Map<List<Source>, List<Destination>>(MySourceList.ToList());
```

I am stuck with this for days, Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to map the CustomObjectSource to CustomObjectDest as well.

This should do it:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<CustomObjectSource, CustomObjectDest>();
            c.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
              .AfterMap((Src, Dest) => Dest.NestedProp = new CustomObjectDest
              {
                  Key = Src.NestedProp.Key,
                  Value = Src.NestedProp.Value
              });
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var MySourceList = new List<Source>
        {
            new Source
            {
                Prop1 = "prop1",
                NestedProp = new CustomObjectSource()
                {
                    Key = "key",
                    Value = "val"
                }
            }
        };

        var destinations = mapper.Map<List<Source>, List<Destination>>(MySourceList.ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Tamas Ionut . such petty thing missed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to point out, The mapping is successful even without the .AfterMap part.